# Fetch POST Request doesn't return response sent using res.send('sampletext');

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, fetch-api

I have a cloud function which is triggered using the fetch POST request from the client browser, but the response to the fetch call doesn't contain the response text from the cloud function(res.send("sampletext"))

Cloud Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })

exports.unlock = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        res.send('bsdasda');
    })
})
```

Fetch POST request on client browser

```
fetch("https://us-central1-closing-ratio-32360.cloudfunctions.net/unlock", {
  method: "post",
  mode: "cors"

}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
});
```

This is the fetch response on the client browser

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://us-central1-closing-ratio-32360.cloudfunctions.net/unlock", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body
:
(...)
bodyUsed
:
false
headers
:
Headers {}
ok
:
true
redirected
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
""
type
:
"cors"
url
:
"https://us-central1-closing-ratio-32360.cloudfunctions.net/unlock"
__proto__
:
Response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
fetch("https://us-central1-closing-ratio-32360.cloudfunctions.net/unlock", {
  method: "post",
  mode: "cors"
})
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((text) => {
  console.log(text)
});
```